# Is it advisable to create a seperate class for JavaFX UI building if done entirely through objects rather than FXML

Tags: java, class, javafx

I'm figuring out whether or not to build my application based on FXML or plain Java. This is because we are not allowed to use the scene builder.

So my problem is whether or not to use one class to build the entire UI through various methods rather than using multiple FXML Files.

If the class option is the best way then should I implement 1 UI Stage per class or all in one

I've used only FXML upto now but when i tried integrating JFoenix i realized that there was no FXML Code given so this was an issue for me

Comment: I am afraid this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it will primarily receive opinion-based answers. Please take the [tour] and read up on [what types of questions should not be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I advice you to use JavaFX even when you have to hardcode it because even then your Code will be simpler. Creating an own UI is very complex and nothing for beginners. It needs a team of pro devs to create something like JavaFX. Then in JavaFX all methods you could dream of are included. So if I were you i would use JavaFX because it is a good and existing way to do it.

Comment: Thats great info. But adding to this, how do you suppose I store that information? Do I make a class fully dedicated to building the UI or?

Comment: You could hard code the fxml file without scenebuilder or use somthing like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLkOX4Eez6o) @ryan

Comment: Yes I think this is the best method to do it but you also can add it in the start method (very messy). But like you I always used fxml and scenebuilder so I can't help you anymore further with my solution. I am sorry @ryan